# Difference between following implementation of structure in c++

Tags: c++, tree, structure

```
struct node 
{
    int data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};
///////////////////
struct node
{
    int data;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};
```

I am unable to figure what's the difference between these two implementations. Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: None in C++, but the second is invalid C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't any difference in C++.

In C a struct tag is not usable as the name of a type (although you can typedef a name the same as the tag and use the typedef).  In C++ you don't have to go through that palaver.  The first form is only allowed for backwards compatibility with C.